# How to fully dump mySQL database via workbench?

Tags: backup, mysqldump, mysql-workbench, export

I am exporting database in SQL file using workbench. Export is done successfully, but when I import data and compare record counts with older database, some of the records are missing. Not all records are exported in some table. I don't know what i can do so no records are missed.

Comment: Start by looking at the dump. Is that complete or are the records already missing there?

Comment: @MikeLischke My database size is showing 7.9 GB, but .dump file is 4 GB only.

Comment: @MikeLischke also i am migrating from mysql 5.5 to 5.7

Comment: Hi @MikeLischke one more update: I have again exported database, this time export file's size was proper but while importing, it did not import all data.